# webpack compile error on require(imagePath)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to dymaically load an image in ReactJS.  So far, what I've found on the internet has not worked.

My react component looks like this:

```
class ReadOnlyTableRow extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let optionImage = require('../assets/option.jpg');
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src={optionImage} />
                    {this.props.data.type}
                </td>
                <td>{this.props.data.symbol}</td>
            </tr> 
        );
    }
}
```

and the webpack error I get is this:

> ERROR in ./src/assets/option.jpg Module parse failed:
>   C:\Java\src\options\web\src\assets\option.jpg Unexpected character '?'
>   (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected character '?' (1:0)

I tried adding a loader to my webpack, but that gave different errors.  So I removed it from my webconfig file.

and my webpack.config file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ] }
      }   
    ]
  }
};
```

What am I missing? or doing wrong?
Thnx,
Matt

**Addendum**:
When I include this in my webpack.config

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=25000'
      }         
    ]
  }
```

I get another error:

> WARNING in Loader
>   C:\Java\src\options\web\node_modules\url\url.js?limit=25000 didn't
>   return a function

The structure of my project is such:
src

```
|---Components
     ---ReadOnlyTableRow 
|---assets
     ---option.jpb
```

here's the package.config file

```
{
  "name": "engine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "engine UI written in React",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --port 8112",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "mpr",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-currency-input": "^1.2.6",
    "react-date-picker": "^5.3.28",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5"
  }
}
```

Thnx, Matt

Comment: you need file-loader or url-loader for parsing images. also require your image above of your class ReadOnlyTableRow .

Comment: and what loader is that?  Ive tried one and didnt resolve anything. this is one I used:      {
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=25000'
    }

Comment: `loader: 'url?limit=25000'`... what is your image loader?! what about using this : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: same error as the first error.   Could the problem be that the image is in a folder that is at the same level the component?  I've added more notes above

Comment: no, I don't think so..what is your devDependencies in package.json?

Comment: its posted above.    "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5"
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158548/discussion-between-emad-emami-and-tatmanblue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used file-loader, per @Emad suggestion in the comments above. Additionally, I needed to use a different web.config which is different than the directions provided for file-loader.  The web.config changes are as follows.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {   
    loaders: [     
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {}
      }        
    ]     
  }
};
```

I changed my javascript code to pull in the image via the import statement:

```
import reloadImage from './../assets/reload-sm.png';
```

Thnx
Matt